# Al dar un clic me manda varios registros a la BD

Tags: javascript, ajax

Buen día, tengo scroll infinito para traer las respuestas de la base de datos y en cada respuesta tengo un botón, pero al ir haciendo scroll para que aparezcan mas respuestas, hay unas respuestas que al dar clic en el botón me guarda dos registros y cuando llegas a la ultima respuesta y regresas hacia arriba para dar clic en cualquier otra respuesta te manda 3 registros y la respuesta que sigue te manda otros 3 registros dando un solo clic y así te sigue aumentando el envió de registros duplicados a la base de datos y conforme vallas haciendo scroll hacia arriba te siguen aumentando los registros en cada respuesta.

Este es el código de mi scroll:

```
 $(window).on("load", function(){

  var base = 0;
  var tope = 3;
  var reachedmax = false;
  var idConsulta = $("#idConsulta").val();
  //console.log("idConsulta", idConsulta);

  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
      getData();
  });

  $(document).ready(function(){
    getData();
  });

  function getData() {
    if (reachedmax)
      return;

      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        data: {
          base: base,
          tope: tope,
          idConsulta: idConsulta,
        },
          success: function(respuesta){
            if (respuesta == "reachedmax"){
              reachedmax = true;
            }else{
              base += tope;
              //console.log("base", base);
              $(".results").append(respuesta);


            }

          }

      });

    }
})
```

Este es el código del botón:

```
$(".boton").click(function(){

    var idRespuesta = $(this).attr("idRespuesta");
    //console.log("idRespuesta", idRespuesta);
    var idUsuario = localStorage.getItem("usuario");
    //console.log("idUsuario", idUsuario);
    var rutaRespuesta = "general";
    //console.log("rutaRespuesta", rutaRespuesta);
    var valorRespuesta = 1.0;

    if(idUsuario == null){

      swal({
        title: "Debe ingresar",
        text: "Para poder calificar las respuestas",
        type: "warning",
        confirmButtonText: "¡Cerrar!",
        closeOnConfirm: false
      },

      function(isConfirm){
        if(isConfirm){
          window.location = localStorage.getItem("rutaActual");
        }
      });

    }else{

      /*=============================================
      VERIFICAR SI YA DIO CLIC
      =============================================*/

      var datos = new FormData();
      datos.append("idRespuesta", idRespuesta);
      datos.append("idUsuario", idUsuario);
      datos.append("rutaRespuesta", rutaRespuesta);

      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        data: datos,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(respuesta){
          console.log("respuesta", respuesta);

          if(respuesta == 0){
          swal({
            title: "No puede calificar mas de dos veces.",
            type: "warning",
            confirmButtonText: "¡Cerrar!",
            closeOnConfirm: false
          },
          function(isConfirm){
            if(isConfirm){
              window.location = localStorage.getItem("rutaActual");
            }
          });

      /*=============================================
      GUARDAR DATOS
      =============================================*/

          }else{

            $(this).addClass("btn-outline-primary active");

            var datos = new FormData();
            datos.append("idRespuesta", idRespuesta);
            datos.append("idUsuario", idUsuario);
            datos.append("rutaRespuesta", rutaRespuesta);
            datos.append("valorRespuesta", valorRespuesta);

            $.ajax({
              method: "POST",
              data: datos,
              cache: false,
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,

              success:function(respuesta){
                console.log("respuesta", respuesta);
              }

            })

          }
```

Comment: Al darle click se te están enviando varias peticiones ajax? verificaste eso con la consola del navegador?

Comment: Si, ya lo verifique con la consola y en unas respuestas me manda un solo registro y en otras me manda dos, lo que he visto es que al llegar la barra del scroll al tope y traerme otras respuestas, la primera respuesta de las tres nuevas que me trajo es la que envía dos registros y asi sigue cada ves que llega al tope.

Comment: Es decir, la primera vez que le das click manda una sola petición, cuando le das la segunda vez dos veces la petición y asi sucesivamente no?

Comment: Por ejemplo al cargar por primera ves la pagina me trae tres respuestas y en estas no hay problema doy clic en el boton de cada una y me guarda un solo registro, pero cuando llego al tope y me trae otras tres respuestas y doy clic en la primera de esas tres me manda dos registros y las otras dos respuestas que siguen me guarda un solo registro y asi puedo seguir y me sigue pasando lo mismo hasta llegar a la ultima respuesta y cuando me regreso hacia arriba para dar mas clic ahora no guarda 2 registros, ahora guarda en unas respuestas 3, en otras 4, 5,6,7, etc.

Comment: El evento click del botón lo tienes fuera de la función `$(window).on("load"...`?

Comment: Agregaste el codigo del boton, pero no como se carga ese codigo, es necesario para conocer tu problema, aunque ya se cual es :) segun el comentario de @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav estas agregando el evento mas de una vez.

Comment: El codigo del boton lo llamo desde el php donde esta el html de las respuestas y en el boton llamo en la clase la funcion del boton.

Comment: De hecho el evento del boton se llama en cada una de las respuestas, en el php tengo el html que le da el formato a cada una, eso es a lo que se refieren sobre que se esta llamando mas de una vez el evento?

Comment: ok trata de colocar `$(".boton").unbind('click')` justo antes de  `$(".boton").click(function(){` y me dices como te fue

Comment: No me funciono con el unbind, pero encontré los eventos preventDefault y stopImmediatePropagation, al utilizar estos eventos antes del ajax ya no me envio registros duplicados, muchas gracias @David Leonardo Molina Ruiz Dav